# Как авторизоватся с помощю python?

Tags: python, selenium, requests

Сайт http://nspi.uz авторизация  реализовано с помощю wp recall. просто с requests не получается пишу бот который каждый день посещает сайт с моими данными помогите !!!

Answer (score 2):

минимальный пример заполнения полей и нажатия кнопки:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep

chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get('http://nspi.uz/?page_id=8014')
sleep(6)

driver.find_element_by_name('user_login').send_keys('Ahmedov Temir')
driver.find_element_by_name('user_pass').send_keys('Ahmedov_Temir')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-form-rcl"]/form/div[4]/input[1]').click()
```